# Trouble converting multiple PDF files to JPEG files using Ghostscript from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, pdf, for-loop, type-conversion, ghostscript

I have several (thousand) multipage PDF files that I am trying to convert to JPEG files (one file for each page of each PDF) with Ghostscript. I have the following batch file, but I can't get it to work properly.

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
  gswin64.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile=p%03d.jpg %%f
)
```

The loop seems to work okay in the sense that it is opening the files. It is going wrong at the "p%03d.jpg" -- I'm guessing that the loop sees the "%0" and for some reason inserts the name of the batch file. I get the following error:

```
**** Could not open the file pC:\Users\bmjones\Downloads\convert.bat3d.jpg
```

("convert.bat" is the name of the batch file)

I'm guessing that even if I got this to work, I would have another problem. When I manually run:

```
gswin64.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile=p%03d.jpg [file name].pdf
```

It works fine. I get a set of files names 001.jpg, 002.jpg, etc. But I would like them to be numbered differently. So, if my first two files have 3 and 2 pages respectively, I would like to have out something like this:

> f1_pg1.jpg, f1_pg2.jpg, f1_pg3.jpg, f2_pg1.jpg, f2_pg2.jpg

Comment: So `gswi64.exe` uses a percent sign as a wildcard in the `-sOutputFile` param?  If you're doing this from a `.bat` script you'll probably need to double-pump the `%` so it'll be treated as a literal percent sign, and not a script argument or variable.  Try `-sOutputFile=p%%03d.jpg`

Comment: @rojo That works great, thanks! I still need to find a way to change the file header in each iteration of the loop so that I'm not writing over the files, but this is a great first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a counter for unique filenames, you could set the name of the output files based on the names of the PDFs.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.pdf) do (
    gswin64 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile="%%~nI_p%%02d.jpg" "%%~I"
)
```

`%%~nI` gets the base name without extension of each PDF.  The `"%%~I"` just makes sure filenames containing spaces don't break things.  Enter `help for` in a console window and see the last two pages for more information about this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, with a little help from @rojo, I think I've got this (I'm certainly open to better solutions)

```
set /a c=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    set /a c=c+1
    set FNAME=f_!c!_p%%02d.jpg
    gswin64.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile=!FNAME! %%f
)
```